# prevention of clear data of an application

Tags: android

I am using android phone I have an app that records phone calls and hide it as temporary files.

it is being deleted by using app manager from clear data option. ho can I prevent temporary files to delete. from app manager.

Answer (score 0):

Give  android:manageSpaceActivity value in application tag which is you want to launch when user click on clear data option.

```
<application android:label="SampleApp" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                 android:manageSpaceActivity=".ActivityYouWantToLaunch">
```